# Xcode - deleted images appearing as warring

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image

I have problem with resurces that i deleted long time ago, and i still see warining in xCode.

[image]

I check Copy Bundle Resurces in Targets and clear project... Nothing happens. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: these images are probably still set on GUI components... but removed from project

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking the status of these files in your SVN repo, they may still be in the state of being added but not committed.